# Can Azure Service Bus be used directly through the AMQP protocol without JMS? Would a spring-amqp implementation for Service bus be feasible?

Tags: azureservicebus, spring-amqp, qpid, azure-sdk-for-java

The [spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/spring/spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms) Spring Boot starter allows to use Azure Service Bus via the JMS 1.0 or 2.0 API depending on the configured pricing for Azure Service Bus. This implementation seems to emulate the JMS functionality through the use of [Apache QPID](https://qpid.apache.org/) .
Is there any implementation of [spring-amqp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp) for Azure Service Bus? Is the [spring-cloud-azure-starter-integration-servicebus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/spring/spring-cloud-azure-starter-integration-servicebus) using AMQP or JMS?

Answer (score 1):

Spring AMQP only supports AMQP 0.9.1, not 1.0; its only implementation is for RabbitMQ.